# React Native: keyboard covers cursor. Some-weird-times

Tags: react-native, scrollview, textinput

Why numbers in plain text breaks normal keyboard behaviour? It's so crazy!

I have a hughe text field that overflows screen size.
I tried to make it with just `TextInput`, but when I overscroll it to the top or to the bottom, app manages this like just touch event and pops up keyboard when it actually do not needed. Sometimes even usual scrolling becomes considered as text selection. This is undesirable behavior.

So, I put `TextInput` inside `ScrollView` and that issues goes away, but becomes a weird new one. When I touch some word (only letters characters) at the bottom of the screen, the keyboard pops up and text scrolls up to help me see the cursor above the keyboard. With words it behaviours as I want (photo below).

[image]

**The problem is here>>** But when I point some number, alpha-numeric, or blank row in the bottom of my text, the keyboard appears, **but the text doesn't jump up**. So I can't see the cursor and must scroll down manually (photo below: see the cursor leaved upon keyboard area).

[image]

Why numbers are blocking this stuff?

Environment: React Native 69.6, Expo 46, Android smartphone, Android Studio

My sipmlified code:

```js
import React from "react";
import { StyleSheet, TextInput, ScrollView } from "react-native";

export default function MyScreen() {
    return (
        <ScrollView
            style={{ flex: 1 }}
            contentContainerStyle={{
                // flex: 1,     <--- if uncomment this, I come back to the first issue
                paddingHorizontal: 10,
                paddingVertical: 5,
            }}
        >
            <TextInput
                multiline={true}
                style={{ fontSize: 16 }}
                value={`Lorem Ipsum...`}
            />
        </ScrollView>
    );
}
```

I tried different combinations of `KeyboardAvoidingView`, `KeyboardAwareScrollView`, different layouts and `View`s nestings. `KeyboardAvoidingView` helps with cursor but it disorders my layouts. I think, the resolving should be simple. How to deal with it?